# How to show log between current branch and its remote counterpart

Tags: git, git-log

Sometimes after fetching from remote repository I see my branch is behind:

```
> git status
On branch develop
Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 7 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

Before updating my local branch I would like to see the log of what I'm about to get. I can do it using

```
> git log develop..origin/develop
```

Since I'm already on the `develop` branch, is there a way to do the above with less typing?  That is, without providing local and remote branch names?

This would be especially useful since I often switch to feature branches and would like to see such logs for those, too.

Comment: Do not forget the most popular IDEs like InteliJ - based have this option from the box. In InteliJ - based in git window choose origin/develop and press compare with current

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a short and branch-agnostic way is to use the `@{upstream}` [construct](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem) :

```
git log ..@{u}
```

(Note : since the first part of the range is omitted here, `HEAD` is implied, but the full verbose syntax would be `HEAD..HEAD@{upstream}`.)

---

And of course it's very handy to have it as `alias.behind` (for example) since it'll use whatever branch you're on.

**Edit after comments** : I added the useful counterpart `alias.ahead` to check commits about to be pushed (there's a catch : while `@{upstream}` refers to the remote branch where your config will pull *from*, the branch set in config to push *to* is `@{push}` ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtpushemegemmasterpushemempushem))). In *some* specific 3-way settings, these may differ, but in most simple workflows both point to the same branch of the same remote. But it's just in case.

```
git config --global alias.behind 'log [any format option you prefer] ..@{u}'
git config --global alias.ahead 'log [any format option you prefer] @{push}..'
```

Comment: I didn't dare to ask for an alias, but here it is nonetheless. Thank you :-)

Comment: And when I'm ahead, I can do `git log @{u}..` to see what the remote is missing.

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak Absolutely :-) I use both myself.

Comment: As a last note, three-dots syntax (`A...B`) would give the symetrical diff, so both `A..B` and `B..A`