# List only local commits of a local branch

Tags: git

I am working on a tool and for it i need a git command which will show only the local commits of a branch (ignoring the one's that came from let's say master or any other branch). I am using C# Process.Start with cmd in order to process the data.

I am new to git and to git terminology and i don't know how to formulate my search in order to find what i need.

I tried experimenting with `git log` but i don't know how to limit the results with it.

Comment: My branch is based on master, but its not pushed to remote yet, is it possible with git log to show only the local commits of my branch?

Comment: When i run it it shows the commits from master as well, i need it to show only the local commits.

Comment: I failed to express myself nicely, now i updated my question. I need this information for a tool that i'm working on.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, I updated my question again.

Comment: Maybe close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72348324/1057485). Once your branch's remote counterpart is set, you'll be able to see commits which exist only locally with `git log @{push}..`

Comment: If i set the remote counterpart it beats the purpose of the question, this is not the problem that i am trying to solve.

Comment: It's simple. Get commits from remote branch, and get commits from local (which includes also `master` or `main` branches, whatever). And then simply find last remote commit, find the same commit hash locally - and every later commit will be what you need. Do you use bash, or powershell for this task? I guess it will be straightforward to implement such solution.

Comment: I am using **cmd** to run my commands. But also how can i do this without specifying explicitly on which branch my branch is based?

Comment: It's important to understand that in git, **commits don't record which branch they belong to**, and branches don't record when they were created or how. When we say "commit x is on branch y", we really mean "commit x is part of the history reachable from the commit currently pointed at by branch reference y". So in the general case, there's no way to find "commits since I created the branch", or "commits not on the parent branch"; the best you can do is "commits reachable from y but not z", or possibly "commits reachable from y but not any other *currently existing* branch pointer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All permutations of "what are the commits" are likely answered by [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log). To establish a known state, consider the following actions:

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git checkout -b some-branch
$ echo "something" >> README.md
$ git commit -a -m "Updating readme"
```

This is simulating creating a new branch with one commit on it.

## List only local commits of a branch

The title question is achieved by for example:

```
$ git log --oneline origin/master..HEAD
4b393e2 (HEAD -> some-branch) Updating readme
```

This is comparing the tip of origin/master to the tip of the current branch. To get this result irrespective of which branch is currently checked out:

```
$ git log --oneline origin/master..some-branch
4b393e2 (some-branch) Updating readme
```

## ignoring the [commits] that came from master

This statement in the body is slightly different than the title question, as there is no reference to the remote. This is achieved by using git log referencing the two local branches:

```
$ git log --oneline master..some-branch
4b393e2 (some-branch) Updating readme
```

In the example here the result is the same, but of course if there are commits on master which have not been pushed to the remote results would differ.